# Convergence of sequences of suprema and infima

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded sequence. We define $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$a_N := inf\{x_n \mid n \geq N\}$$
$$b_N := sup\{x_n \mid n \geq N\}$$
$$l := \lim_{N \to \infty} a_N$$
$$L := \lim_{N \to \infty} b_N$$
1. Prove that $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges $\iff$ $l = L$.
2. Prove that there exist subsequences such that one converges to $l$ and the other to $L$.

I've proved $a_N$ is monotonic increasing, $b_N$ is monotonic decreasing, that $a_N \leq x_N \leq b_N$, $\forall N\in \mathbb{N}$, and that $l\leq L$. It seems that the right-to-left impliation of question 1 can be proved using the sandwich rule...

I'd like a full answer to question 1 and hint(s) for question 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $\Longrightarrow$

Let $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n}$ converge to
$x$.

For $\varepsilon>0$ some $n_{\varepsilon}$ exists such that
$n\geq n_{\varepsilon}\Rightarrow\left|x-x_{n}\right|<\varepsilon$.

Then $a_{N}\geq x-\varepsilon$ and $b_{N}\leq x+\varepsilon$ for
each $N\geq n_{\varepsilon}$ and consequently $x-\varepsilon\leq l\leq L\leq x+\varepsilon$.

This is true for any $\varepsilon>0$, hence $l=x=L$.

1) $\Longleftarrow$

The 'sandwichrule' is fine here: $a_{n}\leq x_{n}\leq b_{n}$ with $a_{n}\uparrow l$, $b_{n}\downarrow L$ and $l=L$.

2)

Note for any positive integer $k$ the set $I_{k}:=\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}\mid l\leq x_{n}\leq l+\frac{1}{k}\right\} $
is infinite.

This makes it possible to choose indices $n_{k}$ such
that $n_{k}\in I_{k}$ and $n_{1}<n_{2}<\cdots$.

Then subsequencence
$x_{n_{k}}$ converges to $l$.

For $L$ their is a similar proof.

Comment: "This is true for any $\varepsilon > 0$, hence $l=x=L$." Intuitively I know this must be true, but how do you rigorously prove this?

Comment: $x-\varepsilon\leq l\leq L\leq x+\varepsilon$ tells us that $0\leq L-l\leq\left(x+\varepsilon\right)-\left(x-\varepsilon\right)=2\varepsilon$. This for every $\varepsilon>0$. This cannot be true if $L-l$ is positive, so $L=l$

Comment: You can prove it rigorously by contradiction: assume that $l\neq L$. Then consequently $L-l>0$ and some $\varepsilon>0$ can be
found - e.g. $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{3}\left(L-l\right)$ - such that $L-l\leq2\varepsilon$
is not true.

Comment: So if I suppose that $l < L (\implies 0 < L-l)$, taking, say, $\varepsilon := \frac{L-l}{4}$ (the inequality should hold for all values of $\varepsilon$), we get $0 < L - l < 2 \varepsilon = \frac{L-l}{2}$, which is a contradiction. Hence $l = L$.

Comment: Yes, that is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If $(x_n)$ converges, say to $p$, then the idea is clearly that $l = L = p$ in this case.
Suppose $l < L$ instead. Then take $\epsilon < \frac{L - l}{2}$, then all terms of the sequence $x_n$ where $n >= K$, for some $K$, lie in $(p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon)$. What does this say about $a_K$ and $b_K$?

Consider $l-1$ first. The $a_n$ increase to $l$, so from some index $m_1$, $a_{m_1} > l-1$, so some $x_{n_1}$, with $n_1 \ge m_1$, $x_{n_1} > l-1$. Now find $m_2 > n_1$ with $a_{m_2} > l-\frac{1}{2}$ and $n_2 \ge m_2$ with $x_{n_2} > l - \frac{1}{2}$, and so on, using $l-\frac{1}{k}$. The sequence of $x_{n_1}, x_{n_2}, \ldots$ converges to $l$. Similarly for $L$, of course.

Comment: I understood perfectly your answer to 2. However, I have trouble understanding the answer to 1. I think you're trying to tell me that $l \leq a_k$ and that $b_k \leq L$ which is a contradiction, but how does choosing $\varepsilon < \frac{L-l}{2}$ imply this?

Answer (score 0):

2) consider the sequence $a_N+1/N$ resp. $b_N-1/N$ and their relations to the partial sequence $x_N,x_{n+1},...$.

The second part of 1) is actually a consequence of 2), since all subsequences of a convergent sequence have the same limit.